# .htaccess IP redirect based on country without installing module

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Found several threads on here about this but they require a module being installed, or require a index.php file.

The requirement is to redirect a visitor to a particular sub-directory on my site if they are from a specific country (in this case, anyone from Czech Republic need redirecting to www.mysite.com/cz)

I'm on a shared (apache) server, and the host of that server doesn't allow modules to be installed, such as this one: https://www.ip2location.com/developers/apache

I ideally want to insert a simple line of redirect to the .htaccess.

My homepage is taken from index.html, if it makes a difference in the answer

Advice on the best solution to make this work please

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: First, apache is made up of modules. Almost everything thing it does it because of a module that is loaded. That's it's design. So if there is a module that enables IP lookup, it's not going to work without it. Otherwise you need to do it in your server side code such as PHP. There is nothing wrong with using modules.

Comment: Updated my question to appease Marc's helpful response. Jack - The host of my server won't let me install any modules which is why I'm stuck there.

Comment: `Advice on the best solution to make this work please` Find a new host that allows this. VPS's or Cloud servers are your best option. Shared hosting is not a good choice if you need customization.

Comment: use server side script that handles cookies to store results of the ip/country request.